# What is the difference between Agora SDK and Agora UI kit?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io, agora-implementation

**Agora UI kit**

https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-uikit?platform=flutter#reference

**Agora SDK**

https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=flutter

> Both have different dependencies. Yet both works, I am confused which one to choose.

> I am new at flutter and I want to implement Agora video call feature in my app. I am really confused what is the difference between UI kit vs SDK?

> Also, I want to implement 1-on-1 video call, with time limit, is it possible on Agora?
> Eg. User1 and User2 have a session for 45 mins and once time is up, call gets disconnected after automatically.

Answer (score 2):

**Agora UI kit**
Agora provide prebuild UI so that the developer can just use that and not need to worry much about the UI part.

**Agora Sdk**
Agora sdk is just the basic sdk where you have to do all the UI and logic part by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in flutter, agora has an official plugin **agora_uikit**
which just has prebuilt UIs and other needed plugins needed for video calling, so you don't need to develop them using their core SDK's (Java/Kotlin/Swift),